# Can't add inherited controls to GroupBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

**Problem:**

I cannot add any controls to a groupbox, if the controls were declared in another form.

---

**Background Information:**

I have `MainForm` which inherits from `Form`.  It provides some functionality which I need in all of my forms, and have also added some custom controls/images which I need in all of the other forms.

With my forms, I reposition the controls/images from the `MainForm` to wherever I need and all is well.

But for some reason, I cannot move these same controls/images into existing `GroupBoxes`.

When I say *can't* I mean that VS is not letting me; when I drag the control over the groupbox, my mouse cursor switches to this "error" sign:

[image]

Comment: It is not clear how your group box is declared. Does that exist in another base class? Are you talking about "Visual Inheritance"?

Comment: @ElectricRouge Presumably yes. `I have MainForm which inherits from Form` :)

Comment: Yes it Winfroms.  @SriramSakthivel all I have done is created a form, which is inherited by othre forms.  When this happens, the widgets appear on the children forms where they would be on the parent forms.  I am able to move the widgets around on the children forms, except i cant put them into groupboxes (declared in children forms).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then you have two or more level of inheritance hierarchy with your form, base class have the `GroupBox` you're trying to modify it in designer via derived form. Am I correct?

In that case VS prevents you to move control to groupbox which is declared in base class?

If yes, There are couple of things to check.

1. Check whether your groupbox is atleast `protected`, so that you can access it in derived class.
2. If yes, While you're dragging the control just right click the mouse(holding left button), then drop it into groupbox. It should work.

If you have troubles yet make the groupbox as `protected internal` and give a try.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, the GroupBox is in the dervied form.  And the controls I am trying to put into it are from the base class.  Ill make sure the controls are atleast protected though

Comment: @BloonsTowerDefence Fine, that doesn't make much difference try my solution. that should help

Comment: I was facing the same problem and it was fixed by mouse "right click" suggestion, I am curious @Sriram Sakthival , what right click actually does ?

Comment: @mohits00691 I have to admit that I don't know what it does and not sure how I knew this. But that's the way I used to solve this problem.